# Failed to install docker on EC2 Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sed

Following [this instructions](http://ghost.stevenisekimart.in/install-docker-on-ubuntu-aws-and-setup-a-container/) to install Docker on EC2 Ubuntu. all went well but this step:

```
$ sudo sed -i '$acomplete -F _docker docker' /etc/bash_completion.d/docker.io
```

> sed: can't read /etc/bash_completion.d/docker.io: No such file or directory

How to go from here? Thanks

Comment: You don't have the file `/etc/bash_completion.d/docker.io` present in your system unlike in the link you've shown.

Comment: @Inian I am just following the instruction to the letter. Now as you indicated the file does not exist, what am I suppose to do?

Comment: Am afraid I will not be able to help you there, probably suggest re-installing it from scratch following the steps.

Comment: @Inian I can confirm the file is there but its name does not have the extension '.io' as stated in the error, so removing the '.io' from the command did not show the error any more

Comment: I have written a quick tutorial about it https://grizzlybit.info/2020-04-11-install-docker-on-ubuntu-18/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following modification to the commands in the link worked for me:

```js
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -y install docker.io

sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/docker.io /usr/local/bin/docker

sudo sed -i '$acomplete -F _docker docker' /etc/bash_completion.d/docker

sudo update-rc.d docker defaults

sudo usermod -a -G docker ubuntu
```

The the rest of the commands in the link

Comment: The change is from "/etc/bash_completion.d/docker.io" to "/etc/bash_completion.d/docker" in the sudo sed(4th command).