# 'system' is not a docker command. See 'docker --help'

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker and not so good in Linux commands. I have followed following commands to install Docker in Ubuntu-14.04.

Using [this guide](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/),

```
apt-get update
apt-get -y install docker.io
ln -sf /usr/bin/docker.io /usr/local/bin/docker

sed -i '$acomplete -F _docker docker' /etc/bash_completion.d/docker.io # it does not work
# sed: can't read /etc/bash_completion.d/docker.io: No such file or directory
```

So using [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39788953/10522579), I have used,

```
sed -i '$acomplete -F _docker docker' /etc/bash_completion.d/docker
update-rc.d docker defaults
```

`docker version` provide following,

```
Client version: 1.6.2
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.6.2
Server API version: 1.18
Go version (server): go1.2.1
Git commit (server): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

And tried with images like `hello-world` & `busybox` successfully. But I failed with commands like,

```
docker system prune
# docker: 'system' is not a docker command. See 'docker --help'.
docker network
# docker: 'network' is not a docker command. See 'docker --help'.
```

Have I missed steps in installation part or did I misunderstand anything?

Comment: Docker 1.6 is _really_ old, to the point where the functionality you're trying to run hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: @DavidMaze I guess for ubuntu 14.04, this is compatible version as I installed after `apt-get update`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used official ubuntu way of doing it.

```
apt-get install docker.io
```

These packages would be outdated. Try using official docker way.

Set up Docker Registry,

```
apt-get update
apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
```

Install Docker CE,

```
apt-get update
apt-get install docker-ce
```

Verify the installation,

```
docker run hello-world
```

Reference is [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938700/how-do-i-install-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

Comment: I assume you have an internet connection from your box where you are installing docker.

Comment: Thanks man, I suspect it but was not sure, I will try these steps and accept answer once I resolve problem.